# How to quickly prototype Java code?

Tags: java, prototyping

Interpreted languages are nice, I can write some quick, prototypical code (i.e. using an interactive shell) for the purpose of exploration before delving into production level code.

What is the best approach for this with Java? Currently I'm creating Maven projects with Eclipse, and exploring things in my test infrastructure using JUnit... but this is less then ideal.

Comment: What is less that ideal about it? You can use the debugger if you want to run an ad hoc expression at any point in the program?

Comment: @PeterLawrey - It's overkill having to create a new project every time I want to trial something contrived - i.e. 3 lines of code - not (necessarily) related to any project I'm working on.

Comment: I have a generic project called `untitled` where I dump pieces of code and I reuse a class called `Main` and `????Main` to run one line to one pagers. I reuse the same project and class files and just change the body to do what I want. (The project also includes every jar I have ever used ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Good to know I'm not the only one doing that sort of thing.

Comment: Java isn't that prototype friendly but when you want to production-ise your application this usually works in your favour.

Comment: I use Dr java which is very lightweight, plus has an interactive panel. I also recommend you to try Jshell, available after jdk 9

Comment: It looks like JShell is the bundled REPL, available in Java 9.  Thanks for the update @Sudip Bhandari.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also check out Eclipse's Scrapbook Page:

Menu>File>New>Other>(search for)Scrapbook Page

Comment: How do we run code saved as a scrapbook page?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use something like [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) ? It's a scripting solution for Java and offers a console-based interactive scripting environment.

Here's the [quick start guide](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/quickstart.html). Note that you can also start a BeanShell console [from within Maven](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/200403.mbox/%3C22DAC946-6C44-11D8-B57A-000A959D0312@yahoo.co.uk%3E).

I've picked BeanShell here since it's the closest thing to Java, but interactive. You could pick another console-based JVM language such as Scala, Jython etc. They're more removed from standard Java since they're different languages, but still offer interoperability with your standard Java components.

Comment: BTW Most debuggers use beanshell or something like it.

Comment: @Brian Agnew - Would you suggest learning Groovy, and using it for the reasons mentioned above, before moving to code in Java?

Comment: I would perhaps recommend Scala instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404917/groovy-vs-scala-vs-jruby-vs-clojure-vs-jython/1404955#1404955 for why

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try out JRebel for quick code tweaking. Or if you are into web development, check Play framework.

http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

http://www.playframework.org/